# How to copy gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried making a game where the player has to jump over obstacles . I want the obstacles to get duplicated  to be at a random position.I wrote the rest of the script in C#.I'm a beginner so I don't know much C#

Comment: It is long time since I worked on unity, but you can check a function called instantiate to create a new object and set your own position for the new object

Comment: Yeahbut I'm a beginner and I don't understand the official Unity documentation

Comment: I suggest you go through the tutorial videos (at least) then start your journey through unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should create a **Prefab** of your **obstacle(s)**, since you want to duplicate it. You can do this by dragging it from the **Scene Hierarchy** into to the **Project>Assets Folder**.

Afterwards, create an **Empty Game Object** inside your **Scene**, and add a script to it, you could call it something like ***ObstacleSpawner***.

I don't want to give you a complete answer... But in the script, you will have a **public GameObject obstacle;** (or **public GameObject[] obstacle;** if there's more than one). After saving the script, the **inspector window** of the **Empty Game Object > ObstacleSpawner (Script)** will now have something called "Obstacle" : "None (Game Object)" inside the box. You can drag the prefab you made of the obstacle inside there.

To **spawn the obstacle**, go back to the script. And inside the **Start() { }** function, use the **Instantiate** function. It takes 3 arguments, 1st is the **GameObject**, so that would  be the **obstacle**. 2nd is a **Vector2(x,y)** or **Vector3(x,y,z)** position, 3rd is a rotation (**Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z)**).

To simply spawn the obstacle where the Empty Game Object is, use **Instantiate(obstacle, transform.position, transform.rotation);**

I'm assuming this is 2d, so you can randomly change the **x** value of the **Vector2** position to make it move side to side, the following example would return a random the **x** position between 0 and 20 units on the **x-axis** from the Empty Game Object: **float num = Random.Range(0, 20);**.

**Instantiate** can be used inside a for loop to be performed more than once (but make sure to change the values so that each object is instantiated at different positions).